Multidimensional arrays in c - problem with pointers
void g()
{
   int a[3][2] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
   printf("%d\n", *(a[2]-1));
}


I need to figure out the output of the function (written in c)
I expected it may fail or print some random stuff, because a[2] is a pointer to an array, and a[2]-1 will point to some random area in the memory. However, the answer is that it prints 4 - I can not figure about why it does that. Any ideas?

Array elements are contiguous. a[2] is a pointer to the third row, and the previous element (last of the second row) has value 4.

Your expectation would be correct if you were creating an array of pointers using malloc(). But it doesn't apply to a 2-d array.

a[2]-1 will point to the previous element a[1][1]. Here is the extract from the standard:  "If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression. In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object ... (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to ... i − n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist."

@user202311: Notice the “provided they exist” part of that. Due to automatic array-to-pointer conversion, a[2]-1 is effectively &a[2][0] - 1, which, per the passage you quoted, would produce a pointer to a[2][-1] if it existed. It does not exist, and therefore the behavior is not defined by the C standard. The fact there is memory prior to a[2][0] and we know what is in it (a[1][1]) does not mean that a[2][-1] exists or that a pointer to it must be produced as the result of the subtraction.

Whenever you have problems with pointers or arrays, I recommend you draw it all out using pen and paper. Add arrows as the pointers to every element. And remember that for any array (or pointer) a, the expression *a (or *(a) in your case) is exactly equal to a[0]. Always do that equivalence change to see if it might help you understand things better.

@EricPostpischil: Thank you. I see what you mean. My understanding was that the rule applies to the multidimensional array as a whole, i.e. a[0][0] is the initial element and a[2][1] is the last one. If the rules apply at the "subarray" level, would this be relevant: "if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array object, the expression (Q)-1 points to the last element of the array object"? a[2] points to one past the last element of array a[1] because the multidimensional array elements must be contiguous.

@user202311 The problem is that formally there are no multidimensional arrays in C. There are arrays of arrays. The language requires contiguous allocation, but pointer arithmetic is only defined on the array level. a[2] points at the last item in the array of 3 array items. That a[1][n] happens to be an array as well is irrelevant, as far as pointer arithmetic on the array a is concerned.

@Lundin: My understanding was that a[2] points to one past the last element of array a[1]. In other words, a[2] is Q in the extract. Thank you for clarifying.

C evaluates *(a[2]-1):

Since a is not the operand of sizeof, the operand of unary &, or a string literal used to initialize an array, it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. As a is an array of 3 arrays of 2 int, its first element is an array of 2 int, which we usually think of as a[0]. So the conversion to a pointer to this yields &a[0].
For a[2], the subscript operator is defined to add the integer to the pointer and then apply *, as if we had written * (&a[0] + 2). Adding 2 to &a[0] produces a pointer to two elements further in the array a, namely the element a[2], so the produced pointer is &a[2]. Then applying * yields a[2]. (Yes, this is the same thing we started with in this step—I am showing the semantics as specified by the C standard and that they produce the result we intuitively think of.)
In a[2]-1, a[2] is an array (it is an array of 2 int), and it is not the operand of sizeof, the operand of unary &, or a string literal used to initialize an array. So it is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element. We usually think of its first element as a[2][0], so the pointer is &a[2][0].
Then for the -, we subtract 1 from the pointer &a[2][0]. This points to an element back one element in the array a[2].

At this point, we have a problem. Subtracting one from &a[2][0] would produce &a[2][-1], but that is outside the bounds of a[2]. We know the element prior to a[2][0] in memory is a[1][1], because arrays (and their subarrays) are laid out in memory contiguously. And thus, when we apply * to this pointer, a C implementation will often produce the value of a[1][1], which is 4.
However, pointer arithmetic is not defined by the C standard when it goes out of bounds of the array the initial pointer points to. Those bounds are the starting element of the array and a position just beyond the last element. For a[2], the bounds are from &a[2][0] (its start element) to &a[2][2] (one beyond its last element, a[2]][1]). &a[2][-1] is not in those bounds.
Some C implementations may support crossing subarray boundaries within a larger array. However, it is also possible that an optimizer in the compiler handles such a crossing differently and produces a different result.

@KonstantinMakarov: Yes, but that does not make the pointer arithmetic defined. The C standard does not require an implementation to implement pointer arithmetic to conform to what is laid out in memory. It only requires pointer arithmetic to work inside an array. If you go outside an array, even a subarray of a larger array, the C standard does not define the behavior. memcpy et al are defined to work in an array and benefit from special treatment of character types.

@KonstantinMakarov: This issue has been discussed previously in [language-lawyer] questions. Please review them before pursuing this.

@KonstantinMakarov: sizeof arr / sizeof ** arr is defined because sizeof arr is defined, sizeof **arr is defined, and / is defined. That has nothing to do with pointer arithmetic. a[2]-1 is not defined because the C standard does not define it. No reasoning about memory layout causes there to be a definition of a[2]-1 in the C standard.
